# As an Google App admin, can I track Google Takeout usage?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business, google-takeout

If my users are using Google Takeout, should I get an email alert with notification that xyz user has used Google Takeout and downloaded their data.

I do not want to restrict, but just monitor, being a Google App admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to track that, unfortunately. The only thing that is being tracked and reported is whenever a Super Admin (or an Admin with respective rights), turns the service on or off, for certain OUs or for the domain as whole. The actual user usage (accessing the takeout, or creating an archive, etc.) is not being tracked. I recently confirmed this with Google support as I was curious of the same thing and as a result turned off the service.